# Term for words meaning both a concept or its best form. Ex: "principles" means "virtue" or "any morals" (good or bad)

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

These might also be examples:
"logic/reason" as in "valid logic" or "any logic".

Comment: Most words have multiple meanings, some general and other varying degrees of specific. Take the word "day" for example.

Comment: I just thought there might be a term similar to "autoantonym", which refers to words that have two distinct opposite meanings. (like "clip" meaning "to attach" or "to cut off")

Comment: Polysemy-with-hypernymy.